# how to get template name in symfony

Tags: symfony1

I want to get my template name in my layout.php. please help me

```
<?php $module_name = $sf_context->getModuleName(); ?>
```

i'm using this above code to get module name, but how to get my current template name.

Answer (score 1):

if you set the template in your action with the `setTemplate()` function you can just get the template name with `getTemplate()`. If you did¡nt assign a template in the action the get Template function will return null.

If you didn't modify the template associated to an action (by default the execute[Action] has a [action]Success.php template) you can make a function like this in your action:

```
$funcName = $this->getActionName();
--> find the first uppercase letter there starts the function name.
--> $new String() = [first letter of name in lowercase] . [rest of the name]
--> $String = string . "Success.php";
```

i'm not advanced enough in php to tell the exacte code but that's the algorithm.

Hope it helped you, good luck;

Answer (score 0):

So symfony is a MVC framework your question belongs to **sfView**

```
/* layout.php e.g. */
var_dump($this->getTemplate());
```

See :

- http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfView#method_gettemplate